# How to check if entered data in a TextBox is matching a list of words from notepad

Tags: c#

I am doing a project on my own. I want to check if the entered text in a TextBox control matches a list of words entered in notepad.

My questions are:

1. How to attach notepad to my project?
2. How to check the words against the list of the words found in notepad?

Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at [this SO help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a start how and when to ask. A starting approach to solve your problem could look like this: disassemble your problem into smaller parts and start implementing them one by one. For example: create a TextBox and a Button; create a button handler event in which the content of the TextBox is fetched; and so on.

Comment: The current answers assume you want to read from a text file, but if you want to read _directly_ from notepad then you can look at UI Automation to see if you can grab the contents of the edit control. Failing that, you'd have to PInvoke WinAPI to read the memory directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//This code first read the words in text file one by one, 
//which are save in notepad file like one word per line 

int aCounter = 0; string aWordInTextFile;
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\notePadFile.txt");
while((aWordInTextFile = file.ReadLine()) != null){
   Console.WriteLine (aWordInTextFile);
   if(textbox.text == aWordInTextFile){
        messagebox.show("String Match, found a string in notepad file");
   }
   aCounter++;

}

file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to attach your notepad to project, just open it using System.Io classes and read it all and check your string using comparison methods.